# Test directory permissions in Python?

Tags: python, windows, permissions, directory

In Python on Windows, is there a way to determine if a user has permission to access a directory?  I've taken a look at `os.access` but it gives false results.

```
>>> os.access('C:\haveaccess', os.R_OK)
False
>>> os.access(r'C:\haveaccess', os.R_OK)
True
>>> os.access('C:\donthaveaccess', os.R_OK)
False
>>> os.access(r'C:\donthaveaccess', os.R_OK)
True
```

Am I doing something wrong?  Is there a better way to check if a user has permission to access a directory?

Comment: The first and third accesses are failing because the \h is getting interpreted as an (invalid) escape sequence

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be complicated to check for permissions in Windows (beware of issues in Vista with UAC, for example! -- see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450210/how-to-check-if-a-file-can-be-created-inside-given-directory-on-ms-xp-vista)).

Are you talking about simple read access, i.e. reading the directory's contents?
The surest way of testing permissions would be to try to access the directory (e.g. do an `os.listdir`) and catch the exception.

Also, in order for paths to be interpreted correctly you have to use raw strings or escape the backslashes ('\\'), -- or use forward slashes instead.

(EDIT: you can avoid slashes altogether by using `os.path.join` -- the recommended way to build paths)

Comment: Good answer, but on your last point, using os.path.join or os.path.sep is better than creating paths manually.

Answer (score 5):

While os.access tries its best to tell if a path is accessible or not, it doesn't claim to be perfect. From the Python docs:

> Note: I/O operations may fail even
>   when access() indicates that they
>   would succeed, particularly for
>   operations on network filesystems
>   which may have permissions semantics
>   beyond the usual POSIX permission-bit
>   model.

The recommended way to find out if the user has access to do whatever is to try to do it, and catch any exceptions that occur.

Answer (score 0):

Actually 'C:\haveaccess' is different than r'C:\haveaccess'.
From Python point of view 'C:\haveaccess' is not a valid path, so use 'C:\\haveaccess' instead.
I think os.access works just fine.

Comment: `'C:\haveaccess'` _is_ a valid path because `\h` doesn't mean anything special, so it works (out of pure luck but it works)

Answer (score 0):

I will provide code for @dF.'s approach of using `os.scandir`/`os.listdir` with [EAFP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56036903/2111778):

```py
def can_access(path: str) -> bool:
    """Check if we can access folder on network drive"""
    try:
        os.scandir(path)
        return True
    except PermissionError:
        return False
```