# Checking File Permissions in Linux with Python

Tags: python

I'm writing a script to check permissions of files in user's directories and if they're not acceptable I'll be warning them, but I want to check permissions of not just the logged in user, but also group and others. How can i do this? It seems to me that `os.access()` in Python can only check the permissions for the user running the script.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You're right that [os.access](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=os.access#os.access), like the underlying [access](http://linux.die.net/man/2/access) syscall, checks for a specific user (real rather than effective IDs, to help out with suid situations).

[os.stat](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=os.access#os.stat) is the right way to get more general info about a file, including permissions per user, group, and others.  The `st_mode` attribute of the object that `os.stat` returns has the permission bits for the file.

To help interpret those bits, you may want to use the [stat](http://docs.python.org/library/stat.html?highlight=stat#module-stat) module.  Specifically, you'll want the bitmasks defined [here](http://docs.python.org/library/stat.html?highlight=stat#stat.S_IRWXU), and you'll use the `&` operator (bit-and) to use them to mask out the relevant bits in that `st_mode` attribute -- for example, if you just need a True/False check on whether a certain file is group-readable, one approach is:

```
import os
import stat

def isgroupreadable(filepath):
  st = os.stat(filepath)
  return bool(st.st_mode & stat.S_IRGRP)
```

Take care: the `os.stat` call can be somewhat costly, so make sure to extract all info you care about with a single call, rather than keep repeating calls for each bit of interest;-).

Answer (score 31):

Just to help other people like me who came here for something a bit different :

```
import os
import stat

st = os.stat(yourfile)
oct_perm = oct(st.st_mode)
print(oct_perm)
# -> 0o100664
```

The last 3 or 4 digits is probably what you want.

See this for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5337329/1814774

Comment: This answer was the most useful for me since I was looking for a file's ACL octal value

Answer (score 14):

```
import os
os.access('my_file', os.R_OK) # Check for read access
os.access('my_file', os.W_OK) # Check for write access
os.access('my_file', os.X_OK) # Check for execution access
os.access('my_file', os.F_OK) # Check for existence of file
```

Comment: As the OP said, this only returns the permissions for the current user, not the full permission set.

Answer (score 9):

Use `os.access()` with flags `os.R_OK`, `os.W_OK`, and `os.X_OK`.

**Edit**: Check out [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539133/python-test-directory-permissions) if you are testing directory permissions on Windows.

Comment: You didnt read the question, os.access only checks permissions for the current user.

Answer (score 9):

You can check file permissions via [`os.stat(path)`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.stat) in conjunction with the [`stat`](http://docs.python.org/library/stat.html) module for interpreting the results.