# Check the permissions of a file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling, file-permissions

I'm trying to check the readability of a file given the specified path. Here's what I have:

```
def read_permissions(filepath):
    '''Checks the read permissions of the specified file'''
    try:
        os.access(filepath, os.R_OK) # Find the permissions using os.access
    except IOError:
        return False

    return True
```

This works and returns True or False as the output when run. However, I want the error messages from `errno` to accompany it. This is what I think I would have to do (But I know that there is something wrong):

```
def read_permissions(filepath):
    '''Checks the read permissions of the specified file'''
    try:
        os.access(filepath, os.R_OK) # Find the permissions using os.access
    except IOError as e:
        print(os.strerror(e)) # Print the error message from errno as a string

    print("File exists.")
```

However, if I were to type in a file that does not exist, it tells me that the file exists. Can someone help me as to what I have done wrong (and what I can do to stay away from this issue in the future)? I haven't seen anyone try this using `os.access`. I'm also open to other options to test the permissions of a file. Can someone help me in how to raise the appropriate error message when something goes wrong?

Also, this would likely apply to my other functions (They still use `os.access` when checking other things, such as the existence of a file using `os.F_OK` and the write permissions of a file using `os.W_OK`). Here is an example of the kind of thing that I am trying to simulate:

```
>>> read_permissions("located-in-restricted-directory.txt") # Because of a permission error (perhaps due to the directory)
[errno 13] Permission Denied
>>> read_permissions("does-not-exist.txt") # File does not exist
[errno 2] No such file or directory
```

This is the kind of thing that I am trying to simulate, by returning the appropriate error message to the issue. I hope that this will help avoid any confusion about my question.

I should probably point out that while I have read the `os.access` documentation, I am not trying to open the file later. I am simply trying to create a module in which some of the components are to check the permissions of a particular file. I have a baseline (The first piece of code that I had mentioned) which serves as a decision maker for the rest of my code. Here, I am simply trying to write it again, but in a user-friendly way (not just `True` or just `False`, but rather with complete messages). Since the `IOError` can be brought up a couple different ways (such as permission denied, or non-existent directory), I am trying to get my module to identify and publish the issue. I hope that this helps you to help me determine any possible solutions.

Comment: Try it with `print("File exists.")` in an `else` block following the `except` block. Is that the sort of behavior you were looking for?

Comment: Try using `return` instead of `print`.

Comment: I just tried that (meaning AirThomas's suggestion). It gave me the same output saying that the file exists when it actually doesn't. I put the `print("File exists.")` in an `else` block after the `except` block. Also, mc10, I just substituted `print` for `return` and it also didn't really seem to do anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking File Permissions in Linux with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1861836/608639), [How can I get a file's permission mask?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5337070/608639), [Checking permission of a file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29517513/608639), [Check the permissions of a file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27434643/608639), etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`os.access` returns `False` when the file does not exist, regardless of the mode parameter passed.

This isn't stated explicitly in [the documentation for `os.access`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#files-and-directories) but it's not terribly shocking behavior; after all, if a file doesn't exist, you can't possibly access it. Checking [the access(2) man page](http://www.unix.com/man-page/opensolaris/2/access/) as suggested by the docs gives another clue, in that `access` returns `-1` in a wide variety of conditions. In any case, you can simply do as I did and check the return value in IDLE:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.access('does_not_exist.txt', os.R_OK)
False
```

In Python it's generally discouraged to go around checking types and such before trying to actually do useful things. This philosophy is often expressed with the initialism EAFP, which stands for *Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission*. If you refer to the docs again, you'll see this is particularly relevant in the present case:

> **Note:** Using `access()` to check if a user is authorized to e.g. open a file before actually doing so using `open()` creates a security
>   hole, because the user might exploit the short time interval between
>   checking and opening the file to manipulate it. It’s preferable to use
>   [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) techniques. For example:
>
> ```
> if os.access("myfile", os.R_OK):
>     with open("myfile") as fp:
>         return fp.read()
> return "some default data"
> ```
>
> is better written as:
>
> ```
> try:
>     fp = open("myfile")
> except IOError as e:
>     if e.errno == errno.EACCES:
>         return "some default data"
>     # Not a permission error.
>     raise
> else:
>     with fp:
>         return fp.read()
> ```

If you have other reasons for checking permissions than second-guessing the user before calling `open()`, you could look to [How do I check whether a file exists using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/82831/2359271) for some suggestions. Remember that if you really need an exception to be raised, you can always `raise` it yourself; no need to go hunting for one in the wild.

---

> Since the IOError can be brought up a couple different ways (such as
>   permission denied, or non-existent directory), I am trying to get my
>   module to identify and publish the issue.

That's what the second approach above does. See:

```
>>> try:
...     open('file_no_existy.gif')
... except IOError as e:
...     pass
...
>>> e.args
(2, 'No such file or directory')
>>> try:
...     open('unreadable.txt')
... except IOError as e:
...     pass
...
>>> e.args
(13, 'Permission denied')
>>> e.args == (e.errno, e.strerror)
True
```

But you need to pick one approach or the other. If you're asking forgiveness, *do the thing* (open the file) in a try-except block and deal with the consequences appropriately. If you succeed, then you know you succeeded because there's no exception.

On the other hand, if you ask permission (aka LBYL, *Look Before You Leap*) in this that and the other way, you *still* don't know if you can successfully open the file until you actually *do* it. What if the file gets moved after you check its permissions? What if there's a problem you didn't think to check for?

If you still want to ask permission, don't use try-except; you're not *doing the thing* so you're not going to throw errors. Instead, use conditional statements with calls to `os.access` as the condition.

Comment: In your last example using `IOError` is very broad. you could also instead catch `FileNotFoundError` or `PermissionError` respectively