# How can I check to see if a file exists before proceeding using Python

Tags: python

I have some code that will find the newest file in a directory and append a time stamp to the file name.  It works great as long as there is a file in the directory to rename.  If there isn't I am getting:

"ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence"

Here's my code:

```
import os
import glob
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
append = now.strftime("%H%M%S")
newest = max(glob.iglob('1234_fileName*.LOG'), key=os.path.getmtime)
newfile = (append+"_"+newest)
os.rename(newest, newfile)
```

Any suggestions for simplifying the code would be appreciated as well as explaining how to only run if a "1234_fileName*.LOG" (note the wildcard) file is detected.

What I need this program to do is run periodically (I can use task scheduler for that) and check for a new file.  If there is a new file append the hours, minutes and seconds to it's name.

Thanks!

Comment: could you edit your title to reflect the question text? If you want to preserve the title then it is a duplicate of: [Check if a file exists using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/82831/4279)

Comment: related: [Check the permissions of a file in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27434643/4279).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `glob.glob()`  that returns a list instead of `glob.iglob()` that returns an iterator:

```
files = glob.glob('1234_fileName*.LOG')
if files:
   newest = max(files, key=os.path.getmtime)
   newfile = append + "_" + newest
   os.rename(newest, newfile)
```

Both `glob()` and `iglob()` use `os.listdir()` under the hood so there is no difference for a single directory.

Comment: Thank you.  Works exactly like I want now.

Answer (score 2):

max() is complaining that you're asking for the largest of 0 items, and throwing a ValueError. You'll have to catch it. This will continue to throw any IOErrors that might occur:

```
import os, glob, datetime

try:
    app = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H%M%S")
    newest = max(glob.iglob("1234_filename*.LOG"), key=os.path.getmtime)
    newfile = (app + "_" + newest)
    os.rename(newest, newfile)
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Comment: `files` is always true in your example because `iglob()` returns an iterator

Comment: You're right, iterators can't be tested that way. OK, then, back to try/except.

Comment: Thank you.  This helped me clean up my code.  However, I still was getting the same error.  Changing files = glob.iglob to files = glob.glob worked.

Answer (score 1):

[`os.access`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#files-and-directories) allows you to check access rights before operations. An example is right under the link.

Also, it's fine to just do things inside a `try` .. `except IOError`.

Comment: Plus one for `try`-`catch`, that's allegedly more Pythonic and it seems as if it would be [more resistant to race conditions](http://blog.rodneyrehm.de/archives/12-Improving-Disk-IO-in-PHP-Apps.html).

Comment: how `os.access()` may help to avoid `"ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence"` in this case?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Sorry, I was answering the title question, "How can I check to see if a file exists before proceeding using Python", not the implied question "why this code fails".