# Checking permission of a file using python

Tags: python, linux, unix

I am running a python script and very first thing to do is, it needs to check a permission of a file before it executes the whole program.

I am currently using `os.system("stat -c '%a' /data/lims/LI")`
is there a better way to do this without using os.system?

my actual coding is

```
checker = int(os.system("stat -c '%a' /data/lims/LI"))
           if checker != 000:
                  print "pass"
```

I want to check the permission of a file which should be a number... something like `755, 750, and others`
if it is a executable permission, than execute.

Comment: Have you checked https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.access ? You could also use `os.stat(filename).st_mode`

Comment: @JohnGalt I think the first one is perfect for me! thank you very much! I just needed to check if it is executable or not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking File Permissions in Linux with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1861836/608639), [How can I get a file's permission mask?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5337070/608639), [Checking permission of a file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29517513/608639), [Check the permissions of a file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27434643/608639), etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use Python's [os.stat(path)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat) or [os.access(path)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.access) directly, e.g. to check it's executable

```
if os.access("/data/lims/LI", os.X_OK):
     print "pass"
```

See [Checking File Permissions in Linux with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861836/checking-file-permissions-in-linux-with-python) for more details.

Comment: I tried this but it prints out the whole stats not just the number of it @NickB

Comment: Simply select from returned tuple what you want... `os.stat(path)[n]`

Comment: @NickB, why don't you include a usage example for Tim so he can see how to use the individual fields in the object returned by `os.stat`?