# Why am I seeing error when the number is 001? Please look at the code below to find the maximum palindrome sum from a given number

Tags: python, palindrome

With number = 001, the error is 'invalid token'.. Please explain why and why 1 and 001 is not treated the same way by the compiler?

```
number = 001

def palindrome(number):
    print ("The number is: ",number)
    str1 = str(number)
    strrev = str1[::-1]

    if (str1 == strrev):
        return True
    else:

        a = int(str1)
        b = int(strrev)
        c = a+b
        print ("Sum with reverse: ",c)
        print ("    ")

        return (palindrome(c))

n = palindrome(number)

print ("Palindrome: ",n)
```

Comment: `001` is not a valid integer in Python, if you want string, write `'001'`

Comment: kindly refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36386346/syntaxerror-invalid-token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**001** is an integer it will work as **1**, instead of **001**. If you need 001 use it as string not an integer. As **001** is invalid integer, but when it comes to string variable it works fine.

Use :

```
stringNumber = '001'
```

Comment: the input is an integer, so only I am converting it to string. i cant make my own input as string.

Comment: Still, if your input is an integer, then the original input representation will still be ignored. If you want leading zeros to mean anything, you will have to store your input as a string, otherwise leading zeros are not stored.