# I cannot use 01,02,03... based index in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Expressing index (0-9) with two digits like- 01,02,03... rather 1,2,3... to work with **Series(Pandas**),
I worte this code in jupyter notebook:

```
students = {01 : 'Ajoy',
           03 : 'Tanzin',
           04 : 'Sakib',
           07 : 'Rahsed',
           10 : 'Shawon'}
s = pd.Series(students)
s
```

I got back:

```
File "<ipython-input-50-ae82df390e04>", line 1
    students = {01 : 'Ajoy',
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

But, when I made a little change, starting index (0-9) with only one digit,the program executed successfully!

```
students = {1 : 'Ajoy',
           3 : 'Tanzin',
           4 : 'Sakib',
           7 : 'Rahsed',
           10 : 'Shawon'}
s = pd.Series(students)
s
```

Output :

```
1       Ajoy
3     Tanzin
4      Sakib
7     Rahsed
10    Shawon
dtype: object
```

Why I can't start the index using the first method?
Is there any bound to do it?
Or, how can I start expressing the index starts with 2 digits?

Answer (score 2):

**How to express the index with 2 digits:**

Will it be OK for you if the index is a string? strings can of course be whatever you like, and pandas allows it:

```py
students = {'01' : 'Ajoy',
           '03' : 'Tanzin',
           '04' : 'Sakib',
           '07' : 'Rahsed',
           '10' : 'Shawon'}
s = pd.Series(students)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
01      Ajoy
03    Tanzin
04     Sakib
07    Rahsed
10    Shawon
dtype: object
```

**Why you can't use int literals with leading zeroes:**

As you can read in the docs for [lexical analysis of integer-literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals):

> Note that leading zeros in a non-zero decimal number are not allowed. This is for disambiguation with C-style octal literals, which Python used before version 3.0.

In short, in C (and in Python before version 3.0), a leading zero before a numeric literal identified an octal literal.
Since Python 3.0, octal literals are identified by `0o`, but to avoid the ambiguity, they decided to not allow leading zeroes at all.

example for how confusing it may be:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Apr  2 2020, 13:16:51) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 0777 == 511
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

leading zeros are not allowed in python 3 you can refer this question
[SyntaxError invalid token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36386346/syntaxerror-invalid-token?answertab=active#tab-top)