# File permission mask in Go

Tags: go, permissions

I was recently playing with file modes and permissions in Go and stumbled upon the output when getting it.

The following code:

```
for _, file := range files {
    fmt.Println(file.Mode()) 
}
```

produces output:

```
drwx------
Lrwxr-xr-x
drwxr--r--
drwx------
drwx------
prw-r--r--
Srw-rw-rw-
Srw-rw-rw-
-rw-r--r--
```

My question is how do I get permissions in numbers like 0777, etc.

Is there a similar way like in python provided in this answer: [How can I get a file's permission mask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337070/how-can-i-get-a-files-permission-mask)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you have the file mode (with [`FileInfo.Mode()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileInfo)), use the [`FileMode.Perm()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileMode.Perm) method. This returns a value of type [`os.FileMode`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileMode) which has `uint32` as its underlying type.

The format you're seeking (e.g. `0777`) is in base 8. You can use e.g. [`fmt.Printf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Printf) with the verb `%o` to print a number in octal format (base 8). Use a width `4` to make it 4 digits, and a flag `0` to make it padded with `0`'s. So the format string for printing file permissions: `"%04o"`.

So print it like this:

```
files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(".")
// Handle err

for _, file := range files {
    fmt.Printf("%s %04o %s\n", file.Mode(), file.Mode().Perm(), file.Name())
}
```

Example output:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 0664 play.go
drwxrwxr-x 0775 subplay
```