# How to interpret os.stat() st_mode value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, python-2.7

I am developing a Mysql based file system for Linux system. I have developed python code to implement basic linux terminal command like cd,ls,pwd,find and grep.

As a part of ls command ,I want to implement ls -l extension.

I have stored st_mode value for all files in database.Now I need to interpret the mode results just as below result and print them.

**drwxr-xr-x 31 sai sai 4096 Apr  2 10:31 sai**

Example : the octal value of **st_mode = 0o0400** .Now I need to retrive/obtain **drwxr-xr-x** from the octal value.

I reffered to [using masking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337070/how-can-i-get-the-unix-permission-mask-from-a-file/5337329#5337329) but did not understand how to obtain the results in the format I want using python.

Please suggest ways to achieve my requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Got it.

Converted the octal value to binary using bin() and then referred to final 9 bits of the binary number to get permission bits.

Comment: it  would be helpful to show your code

Answer (score 0):

Just to extrapolate and show how to do what Sai does in his answer:

To get the permission information from a file, simply use `os.stat(filename).st_mode`, and convert it to octal or binary:

```py
>>> import os
>>> mode = os.stat("my_file").st_mode # can use relative or absolute path
>>> print(mode)
17917
# in octal, the last 3 numbers refer to owner, group and others' permissions
>>> print(oct(mode)[-3:])
775
# in binary, the last 9 numbers show the same info, but grouped as 3+3+3 bits
>>> print(bin(mode)[-9:])
111111101
```

Now, `775` (or `111-111-101`) tells me that the owner of the file is allowed to read, write and exectute the file, and so is everyone in the assigned group. Everyone else however, are allowed to read and execute, but not write to the file.

By converting to binary, it's quite easy to check whether a single permission is "active", and by doing some simple bit-arithmetic we can check whether one of these actors has a specific privilege:

```py
# the bit-mask for owner writing to file:
owner_write = 0b010000000
group_write = 0b000010000
other_write = 0b000000010
# do a bitwise AND and check whether the result is non-zero (or truthy):
if owner_write & mode:
  print("owner can write")
if group_write & mode:
  print("group can write")
if other_write & mode:
  print("others can write")

# this program would output
# "owner can write"
# "group can write"
```