# How do you do a simple "chmod +x" from within python?

Tags: python, chmod

I want to create a file from within a python script that is executable.

```
import os
import stat
os.chmod('somefile', stat.S_IEXEC)
```

it appears `os.chmod` doesn't 'add' permissions the way unix `chmod` does. With the last line commented out, the file has the filemode `-rw-r--r--`, with it not commented out, the file mode is `---x------`. How can I just add the `u+x` flag while keeping the rest of the modes intact?

Answer (score 272, accepted):

Use `os.stat()` to get the current permissions, use `|` to OR the bits together, and use `os.chmod()` to set the updated permissions.

Example:

```
import os
import stat

st = os.stat('somefile')
os.chmod('somefile', st.st_mode | stat.S_IEXEC)
```

Comment: This only makes it executable by the user.  The poster was asking about "chmod +x" which makes it executable across the board (user, group, world)

Comment: Use the following to make it executable by everyone... stat.S_IXUSR | stat.S_IXGRP | stat.S_IXOTH.  Note: that value is the same as octal 0111, so you could just do st.st_mode | 0111

Comment: [My answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30463972/119527) copies the R bits to X, as one would expect from say, a compiler.

Comment: I would do `STAT_OWNER_EXECUTABLE = stat.S_IEXEC`, and use the human readable local constant instead of the gibberish one.

Comment: here's a non-pythonic answer that may be a little more readable: `subprocess.check_call(['chmod', '+x', 'somefile'])` and let's you more easily do operations like `a+rx`.

Comment: Would it not be better to use XOR not OR as then you are only changing the Executable bits of the permission and it is reversible so you are left with the permissions which the file had before being made executable 

`os.chmod('test.sh', os.stat('test.sh').st_mode ^ 111)`

Comment: Does this actually work on Windows?

Answer (score 33):

For tools that generate executable files (e.g. scripts), the following code might be helpful:

```
def make_executable(path):
    mode = os.stat(path).st_mode
    mode |= (mode & 0o444) >> 2    # copy R bits to X
    os.chmod(path, mode)
```

This makes it (more or less) respect the `umask` that was in effect when the file was created: Executable is only set for those that can read.

Usage:

```
path = 'foo.sh'
with open(path, 'w') as f:           # umask in effect when file is created
    f.write('#!/bin/sh\n')
    f.write('echo "hello world"\n')

make_executable(path)
```

Comment: Octal literals changed in Python 3. Instead of `0444`, you'd use `0o444`. Or, if you want to support both, just write `292`.

Comment: @Kevin It [looks like](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#new-syntax) the new syntax has been supported by Python 2.6, so it seems reasonable to use that. (For a compatibility reference point, CentOS 6 ships with Python 2.6).

Comment: I was unaware that Python 3 had remove the traditional octal literals. So thank you for that.

Comment: @AaravPrasad No, it is not the same. You're turning on all X bits while my answer only turns on X bits where R is already on. Also, being a "one-liner" is of absolutely zero value for any real project.

Comment: @AaravPrasad You don't seem to understand what [`umask`](https://manpages.org/umask/2) is or how it works. Even if a process passes `0o777` for the mode to `open()`, the kernel will *mask*-off bits that are set in the process's current `umask`. So if the `umask` is `0o027`, then the resulting file will have mode `0o750`. And as stated in my answer, "This makes it (more or less) respect the `umask` that was in effect when the file was created: Executable is only set for those that can read." When would you ever want a file to be executable by someone who cannot read it? It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 30):

If you're using Python 3.4+, you can use the standard library's convenient [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

Its [Path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path) class has built-in [chmod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.chmod) and [stat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.stat) methods.

```py
from pathlib import Path
import stat


f = Path("/path/to/file.txt")
f.chmod(f.stat().st_mode | stat.S_IEXEC)
```

Answer (score 18):

If you know the permissions you want then the following example may be the way to keep it simple.

Python 2:

```
os.chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0775)
```

Python 3:

```
os.chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0o775)
```

Compatible with either (octal conversion):

```
os.chmod("/somedir/somefile", 509)
```

reference [permissions examples](http://permissions-calculator.org/examples/)

Comment: This should be os.chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0o775)

Answer (score 10):

**Respect `umask` like `chmod +x`**

`man chmod` says that if `augo` is not given as in:

```
chmod +x mypath
```

then `a` is used but with `umask`:

> A combination of the letters ugoa controls which users' access to the file will be changed: the user who owns it (u), other users in the file's group (g), other users not in the file's group (o), or all users (a).  If none of these are given, the  effect  is as if (a) were given, **but bits that are set in the umask are not affected.**

The goal of this is so that you don't accidentally give too many permissions. umask determines the default permissions of a new file, e.g. with a umask of `0077`, `touch newfile.txt` produces  permissions `rw` for the current user because the 77 would exclude group and other (x is not given by default by touch anyways though). And `chmod +x` would similarly only add `+x` for user, ignoring group and other due to the `0011` part of the mask: you would need `chmod o+x`, `chmod g+x`, `chmod go+x` or `chmod a+x` to force them to be set.

Here is a version that simulates that behavior exactly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import stat

def get_umask():
    umask = os.umask(0)
    os.umask(umask)
    return umask

def chmod_plus_x(path):
    os.chmod(
        path,
        os.stat(path).st_mode |
        (
            (
                stat.S_IXUSR |
                stat.S_IXGRP |
                stat.S_IXOTH
            )
            & ~get_umask()
        )
    )

chmod_plus_x('.gitignore')
```

See also: [How can I get the default file permissions in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150826/how-can-i-get-the-default-file-permissions-in-python)

Tested in Ubuntu 16.04, Python 3.5.2.

Answer (score 6):

You can also do this

```
>>> import os
>>> st = os.stat("hello.txt")
```

Current listing of file

```
$ ls -l hello.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 morrison  staff  17 Jan 13  2014 hello.txt
```

Now do this.

```
>>> os.chmod("hello.txt", st.st_mode | 0o111)
```

and you will see this in the terminal.

```
ls -l hello.txt    
-rwxr-xr-x  1 morrison  staff  17 Jan 13  2014 hello.txt
```

You can bitwise or with 0o111 to make all executable, 0o222 to make all writable, and 0o444 to make all readable.

Answer (score 0):

In python3:

```py
import os
os.chmod("somefile", 0o664)
```

Remember to add the `0o` prefix since permissions are set as an octal integer, and Python automatically treats any integer with a leading zero as octal. Otherwise, you are passing `os.chmod("somefile", 1230)` indeed, which is octal of `664`.

Comment: This does sets permissions to an absolute value, it does not do a `chmod +` as asked by OP, which should add new permissions to existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

we can directly call `chmod +x` command in python using `os.system()`

```
import os
os.system("chmod +x somefile")
```

Answer (score 0):

This turns on all executable bits for a file:

`os.chmod("path", os.stat("path").st_mode | 0o111)`