# When saving excel file (openpyxl) and then trying to make excel open it on mac get `Permission denied` error

Tags: python, macos, excel, python-2.7

This code:

```
workbook.save(outputf)    
system('open ' + outputf)
```

generates this error when run on my mac:

```
sh: /Users/tylerjw/Desktop/jim_data/August2013_report.xlsx: Permission denied
```

The file was created with openpyxl.  I have not been able to reproduce the error outside of my application is a tkinter application that is writing a considerable amount of data to that file.

When I run similar code in windows it doesn't error, it opens excel with the file.  The only difference is the absence of the `open` command.

What could case this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my system (mac 10.6.8, python2.7.5, gcc 4.2.1) the following code works fine:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from os import system
wb = Workbook()
outputf = 'test.xlsx'
wb.save(outputf) 
# see below *
system('open ' + outputf)
```

*(see comments: I lost the bet. The error was somewhere else in the code and has nothing to do with system('open ' + whatever))*

I bet there is something wrong with permissions in your new file on your system. Maybe you add
([docu](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_chmod.htm))

```
st = os.stat(outputf)
os.chmod(outputf, st.st_mode | stat.stat.S_IRWXU | stat.S_IRWXG | stat.S_IRWXO)
```

[(with input from other link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791997/how-do-you-do-a-simple-chmod-x-from-within-python)

in the code instead of my commentary ('# see below *') Then it should be possible to open it by everyone and everything...

If it works, this is a workaround. There is a difference between our system and I do not know what difference. If not, well, I did not test it on my system (because I did not have a problem with the code), write a comment and I might play with the settings or maybe someone else has an idea.

Btw.: In a terminal in your folder: What output gives 'ls -l excelfilename' after execution of the python code? What programming environment do you use? I start the program via 'python2.7 pythonscript.py' in the terminal.

Comment: `-rw-r--r--  1 tylerjw  staff  7168 Aug 25 09:25 August2013_report.xlsx` I'm using python 2.7.5 installed with home-brew.  To open the application i'm using the command `python2 pythonscript.pyw`.  `python2` is a link to my 2.7.5 install.

Comment: output from os.stat: `posix.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=4647129, st_dev=16777218L, st_nlink=1, st_uid=501, st_gid=20, st_size=7167, st_atime=1377406987, st_mtime=1377412013, st_ctime=1377412013)`

Comment: Ok, the os.stat gives the same output as ls -l. The permissions seem to be ok. At least, it is the same here. Is it possible for you to open a file generated by Excel and saved with Excel with 'open file' in the terminal?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question.  Are you asking if it is possible for me to open any Excel file using the terminal?  I tested this and it seems to work. Also outside of the application after the file is created I am able to open the file with `open file`.

Comment: If you want to see the problem yourself you can clone my project at  [my github repository](https://github.com/tylerjw/jim_tracker).  Run the application, set the data directory to the same folder (there are excel files in there you need) then go to reports tab and try to save a report.  You should see the error on your console window.  The main application is `jim_tracker.pyw`.  The offending lines of code are in `reports.py` starting at line 82.

Comment: Ok, this has nothing to do with the 'open ...' thing. The problem is in the code. I try to upload on github.

Comment: Ok, I forked jim_tracker.pyw and changed reports.py. Now its fine. The error was that in an if else clause some wrong argument was invoked for system(..).