# How to change permissions of multiple files using os.chmod

Tags: python, shell

I have a directory which contains multiple files (some shell ending with .sh, some text files and some python files ending with .py extension).

I want to add execute permission to all shell files (ending with .sh) using os.chmod command. Basically I want to do this:

```
chmod +x *.sh
```

I tried checking for permissions first by doing this:

```
>>> s = os.stat('*.ksh')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '*.ksh'
```

But it won't work.
How can I do this in pythonic way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`glob` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) to get a list of files, and then loop over them:

```
import glob, os, stat

for name in glob.glob('*.sh'):
    print(name, os.stat(name))
```

And you can use `os.chmod()` as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791997/how-do-you-do-a-simple-chmod-x-from-within-python) to actually add the executable mode bit:

```
for name in glob.glob('*.sh'):
    st = os.stat(name)
    os.chmod(name, st.st_mode | stat.S_IEXEC)
```

Comment: Forgot about glob. Thanks Ben !