# How do I change group execute permissions while preserving every other permission using os.chmod?

Tags: python, chmod

I'm trying to get my code to change the group executability permission using os.chmod while keeping all the other permissions in their original state, but I can't seem to figure out how.

All the chmod numbers change all the permissions.
I want my program to change the group executability permission to True if it's currently False, and to False if it's currently True

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791997/how-do-you-do-a-simple-chmod-x-from-within-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to "flip" the group execute bit you could do this:

```
import os

os.chmod(filename, os.stat(filename).st_mode ^ 0o10)
```

Comment: thanks, that works. However, I don't quite understand the ^ 0o10 part. Would you be able to explain how that flips the group execute?

Comment: @Glyniel The caret is an XOR (bitwise exclusive or). 0o10 is the octal representation of decimal 8 and thus the group execute bit. The effect of XOR is to set a bit on if it's off and vice versa. So, for example, if the file permissions are 0o777 (rwxrwxrwx) and we XOR with 0o10 it becomes 0o767 (rwxrw-rwx). If we then XOR that again with 0o10 it becomes 0o777 (rwxrwxrwx) again

Answer (score 0):

```
stat.S_IMODE(os.stat(your_file).st_mode)
```

"Return the portion of the file’s mode that can be set by `os.chmod()` —that is, the file’s permission bits, plus the sticky bit, set-group-id, and set-user-id bits (on systems that support them)."

You can then check what the current permissions are, and modify them as needed.

Comment: OP's challenge is to "flip" the group execute bit i.e., turn on if currently off and vice versa. This code also raises AttributeError on my platform

Comment: Oops, editing. `S_IMODE` is a function in the `stat` module. I don't know where that `os.` came from

Comment: Fixed that, I understand OP wants to flip a bit. But I thought a more general answer could be useful, to OP or to someone else in the future