# How to check if a text file is open in gedit

Tags: python, unix, ubuntu, gedit

So this is a basic client server socket program.The client sends the file to the server and the server opens it using gedit.

```
p = subprocess.Popen("gedit file", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

I want the code to work like

```
while file_open in gedit:
            wait()
after file_closed and saved
            send to client
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python : Check file is locked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371444/python-check-file-is-locked)

Answer (score 0):

```
while p.is_alive():
    ...
```

I guess... but that will really just keep going as long as the process (gedit) is open ... they may have closed that specific file ...