# How to know when writing a file has been finished?

Tags: c++, windows, file, qt5

I'm writing a program which operates on a file (only reads the file), while another program is writing that file (I've no control over it to use events and I don't know the content of the file). I want a way to know when that program finished writing, to stop my program operating on the file. I used these two method but I don't know which one is reliable and more performance:

1- renaming file to another name, if success, rename it to original name.

2-flush file , if file size has not been changed for a while (e.g 5 sec) then stop operation.

which one is better? is there any better way (more reliable and more performance)?

I'm using windows 7 and qt5.2(or visual studio) for c++.

Comment: what do you mean by "operates on file" does it include read and  write operation or just read operation?

Comment: @GingerJack , it only reads the file.

Comment: you can use IPC for effective communication. Your Writer program sets the event and your reader program will wait on it and when the reader program is triggered ,it should stop reading and  close the handle of the file .

Comment: It is operating system specific. Linux has [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html). BTW, the `tail -f` command on POSIX is doing something quite similar...

Comment: @GingerJack , I've no control over it to use events.

Comment: whats your environment linux,Mac OS or windows

Comment: Is there any string or pattern at the end of the file write. If so, use a Perl script to catch it and then start your program by script

Comment: no there is no pattern in it, I don't know anything about the content of the file

Comment: Did you checked [this answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20722786/2307070)

Answer (score 1):

Qt provides a class called [`QFileSystemWatcher`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemwatcher.html#QFileSystemWatcher) which allows you to monitor files and directories.