# python how to retrieve file flags

Tags: python

os module contains function `chflags` that allows user to modify UNIX file flags: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

Is there a function that would let me see which flags the file currently has?

I am asking about file flags (equivalent of unix command lsattr or chattr) not permissions (chmod etc)

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861836/checking-file-permissions-in-linux-with-python

Comment: No dup, OP is asking for *flags*, not mode bits.

Answer (score 3):

File flags are made available via `os.stat()`.

The POSIX implementation of python's os module returns a `stat_result` object that has an `st_flags` field:

```
import os
st = os.stat(filename)
print(st.st_flags)
```

The possible flag bits are available in the `stat` module as

```
SF_*
UF_*
```

constants.

Comment: I tried this and get `AttributeError: 'os.stat_result' object has no attribute 'st_flags'`

Comment: According to the documentation this attribute may not be available on some Unix systems. Could you please describe your setup?

Comment: It's ubuntu 14.04 LTS, but now I figured out that my os module doesn't even have chflags function :( maybe it's not in my python? I got python 3.4.0

Comment: Linux does not have a `chflags()` system call. It is simply not supported by the operating system.

Comment: However Linux has a [`chattr`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chattr) function and this should/could be available through `os.chflags()`.

Comment: @davidedb Unfortunately, no. `chattr` is not made available via the `os` module even on Linux. Sounds like a good candidate for a feature request, though.

Comment: @dhke In fact the point is that the Linux `chattr` functionalities should be (partially?) available through `os.chflags()`. See also [Python os module lacks the chflags/lchflags methods](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/+bug/969032).