# np.column_stack dimension mismatch sometimes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, stack

```py
if df is None:

    """Using np.column_stack for performance reasons"""
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([paths, file_names, hashes, filesizes]), 
                               columns=['path', 'file name', 'sha256', 'file size (MB)']) 
 
    """Save the df just in case we want to continue later"""
    print(f"Saving progress to {pickle_path}")
    try:
        df.to_pickle(pickle_path)
```

I get this error on the line with `np.column_stack`.

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError
all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 156738 and the array at index 3 has size 156735
```

This line works **most of the time**, but every once in a while I get this error on a script that can have a runtime at almost a half hour, so it is pretty frustrating to get it. Is there some way I could fill NA or something to get the dimensions corrected?

Comment: one way or other you need to test the dimensions, especially the one that occasionally is short.  Then either skip that case, or pad the array.  `column_stack` can't take any corrective action for you.

Answer (score 0):

Array at index 0 refers to `paths`.
Array at index 3 refers to `filesizes`.

Assert that the shapes of paths and filesizes are equal before using `np.column_stack`. There is a dimension mismatch, as you've noticed.

```python
assert paths.shape == filesizes.shape
```

Fill the input array (paths or filesizes) with NA before feeding them into the Dataframe based on an acceptable *criteria*. Randomly filling the arrays with NAs is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks, Grace. I'm thinking the mismatch in dimensions is due to not having permission for some files, and therefore there is nothing that I can think of to put in the column besides NA. I'll investigate possible solutions to this tomorrow.

Comment: @jangles Maybe this resource would be of interest to you [Check permissions for files in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861836/checking-file-permissions-in-linux-with-python)