# Python openfile returing IOError22, even with escaped filename

Tags: python

1. I tried to create a new file with Python26 file()/open() directly inside C:\. User does not have permission to create a new file here.
2. Expectation is that i receive a "Permission denied" error. However i end up receiving invalid file name/mode error on one particular host. This is breaking the error handling of my application .  On all other hosts it is doing fine.
3. All other threads in stack over flow like [Region: IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141761/region-ioerror-errno-22-invalid-mode-w-or-filename) point to wrong file names which i believe is not the case with me.

   ```
   a = file("C:\\new2.txt","w")                                  
   Traceback (most recent call last):  
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                             
   IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename: 'C:\\new2.txt'
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Whey you are calling `file(path,"w")` in windows, Python calls `open()` or `_wopen()` with flags `O_CREAT | O_TRUNC`.

Both this functions can return following codes (as described in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0kc8e3z.aspx)):

> - `EACCES` - Tried to open a read-only file for writing, file's sharing mode does not allow the specified operations, or the given
>     path is a directory.
> - `EEXIST` - 
>     _O_CREAT and _O_EXCL flags specified, but filename already exists.
> - `EINVAL` - Invalid oflag or pmode argument.
> - `EMFILE` -  No more file descriptors are available (too many files are open).
> - `ENOENT` - File or path not found.

As you can see, `EACCES` is not your option as file does not exists.

Now let's take a look at flags:

> - `_O_TRUNC` Opens a file and truncates it to zero length; **the file must have write permission**. Cannot be specified with `_O_RDONLY`.
>     `_O_TRUNC` used with `_O_CREAT` opens an existing file or creates a
>     file.

And one last thing:

> if any value other than the allowed oflag values is specified, the
>   function generates an assertion in Debug mode and invokes the invalid
>   parameter handler, as described in Parameter Validation. If execution
>   is allowed to continue, the function returns -1 and sets errno to
>   `EINVAL`.

So, in your case you will not get `EACESS`. Instead you will get `EINVAL` (22).

You can check this question [How to check if a file can be created inside given directory on MS XP/Vista?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450210/how-to-check-if-a-file-can-be-created-inside-given-directory-on-ms-xp-vista) and this [Python - Test directory permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539133/python-test-directory-permissions)

To try to find solution. As you can see, Windows file access rights hardly can be mapped to POSIX. There are no easy solution.

Comment: If i try the same thing on another machine, i end up receiving permission denied error. I tried to check if there are permssion differences, but i see none.                                                                        `>>> open("C:\\new5.txt","w")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\new5.txt'`

Comment: @SudhakaraRao is it running the same version of Windows? I saw, that different versions of UAC + different treatment  of running programs (i.e. is it running in compatibility mode) can cause funny things.